# How can I deploy a Sinatra-based Ruby web app to Heroku?

Tags: ruby, git, heroku, sinatra

How can I deploy a Sinatra-based Ruby web app to Heroku?

I have a Sinatra-based [web application](https://github.com/dpisarenko/50web/tree/heroku/servers/dev). When I want to run it locally, I do following:

1. In the command line, I go to the directory [servers/dev](https://github.com/dpisarenko/50web/tree/heroku/servers/dev).
2. Run `thin start -R songcontest.ru`

Now I want to deploy the same application to Heroku. I followed the first few steps of a tutorial ([step 1](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-jruby#introduction), [step 2](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#introduction), [step 3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#set-up)).

Now I want to run `git push heroku master`, which is the next step in deploying the app to Heroku. When I do it, I get the following error message:

```
remote:  !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
remote:       to use for this application automatically.
remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
```

[image: Push rejected]

How can I fix it (make my application run on Heroku) ?

Comment: Have you had a look at the recommened article from the error message?

Comment: @thesecretmaster Yes. I set the build pack and I put the Gemfile into the root directory. This (presence of a Gemfile) is what the detection script of the Ruby build pack checks. But I'm still getting the error message (build pack not detected). I asked the Heroku support about that. Current version is available at https://github.com/dpisarenko/50web/tree/heroku . I tried to run the app locally (`bundle install`, then `bundle exec rackup -p 9292 songcontest.ru`) and it worked (a page was available at `localhost:9292`).

Comment: @thesecretmaster More details on what I tried so far are available at http://altruix.cc/song-contest/deployment-on-heroku/ .

Comment: What if you try locally `thin start -R songcontest.ru`? Does that work? Also, do you have a Procfile or config.ru?

Comment: Yes, `thin start -R songcontest.ru` works. No, I don't have a `Procfile`, nor `config.ru`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When deploying from a different branch into Heroku's master branch, you need to specify the branch in the push command: `git push heroku heroku:master`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Deploying Rack-based Apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack) heroku docs. You'll need a config.ru file and potentially a Procfile to start your webserver.